# Pentaho CDA: Basic Authentication and CORS conflict

Tags: rest, tomcat, cors, pentaho, basic-authentication

Working on a web app which queries Pentaho BI server 7 with a Tomcat 8 inside I'm facing some issues.

First of all to avoid CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) problems I have added the CORS filter inside the web.xml config file of the tomcat:

```
  <filter>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
     <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
     <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>   
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

Afterwards, everything was fine until it was necessary to get some resources through Pentaho CDA (Pentaho Community Data Access). I've added a Basic Auth header and one line in the plugin settings file (pentaho-solutions/system/cda/settings.xml):

```
<allow-cross-domain-resources>true</allow-cross-domain-resources>
```

Every request my aplication does gets the same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/pentaho/plugin/cda/api/doQuery?path=/whatever/dashboard.cda&dataAccessId=mdxGetSmth. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:xxx' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.

The funny thing is that the same query is working in Postman (of course with the same Basic auth header) just because Postman just jumps over the OPTIONS (preflight) request.

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226463/how-do-i-configure-tomcat-not-to-perform-authentication-or-authorization-on-cors, or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069640/whitelist-security-constraint-in-web-xml

Answer (score 0):

Used Ngnix as Reverse proxy on Apache-Tomcat and resolved this CORS error